# SharedPreferences returns empty value by key

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have logic for creation notifications using AlarmManager.setRepeating(..). I successfully created some notifications with special time for showing it. Here I save SharedPrefereces value by some id using **storeSelectedDays()**

And there is some BroadcastReceiver which runs when notification should be shown (the time has come).
Here I read value from SharedPreferences by this id using **getStoredSelectedDays()**.

```java
public class SelectedDaysManager {

    private final static String PREFERENCES_KEYS = "sp_key";
    private final static String KEY = "KEY_";

    private final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    public SelectedDaysManager(Context context) {
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
            PREFERENCES_KEYS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public List<Integer> getStoredSelectedDays(long id) {
        final List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        final Set<String> set = sharedPreferences.getStringSet(KEY + id, 
            new HashSet<String>());
        for (String item : set) {
            result.add(Integer.parseInt(item));
        }
        Log.d("TIME TIME", String.format("Got selected days: KEY = %s, 
            DAYS = %s", KEY + id, result));
        return result;
    }

    public void storeSelectedDays(long id, List<Integer> selectedDays) {
        final Set<String> selectedDaysSet = new HashSet<String>();
        for (Integer day : selectedDays) {
            selectedDaysSet.add(String.valueOf(day));
        }
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putStringSet(KEY + id, selectedDaysSet);
        editor.commit();
        Log.d("TIME TIME", String.format("Saved selected days: KEY = %s, 
        DAYS = %s", KEY + id, selectedDaysSet));
    }

}
```

**AlarmReceiver.java**

```java
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ...
        final List<Integer> storedSelectedDays = 
            App.getInstance().getSelectedDaysManager()
                .getStoredSelectedDays(reminderId);
        ...
    }
```

**Application**

```java
public class App extends Application {
    private static App sInstance = new App();

    public static BefitApp getInstance() {
        return sInstance;
    }

    private SelectedDaysManager selectedDaysManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sInstance = this;
        selectedDaysManager = new SelectedDaysManager(getApplicationContext());
        ...
    }

    public SelectedDaysManager getSelectedDaysManager() {
        return selectedDaysManager;
    }
}
```

**Now, what my problem is:**

I save 2 reminders:

storeSelectedDays(1, /*some int list*/[1,2,3]);

storeSelectedDays(2, /*some int list*/[1,2,3]);

after that file in sharedpreferences looks like this:

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
<map>
    <set name="KEY_2">
        <string>3</string>
        <string>2</string>
        <string>1</string>
    </set>

    <set name="KEY_1">
        <string>3</string>
        <string>2</string>
        <string>1</string>
    </set>
</map>
```

But

when BroadcastReceiver runs first time

**getStoredSelectedDays(1)** returns [1,2,3]

when BroadcastReceiver runs second time

**getStoredSelectedDays(2)** returns []

So somewhy during second run (id == 2) set is empty. What do I do wrong?

**---EDITED---**

Behaviour:

1. I create 2 reminders: first - 9:00, second - 9:10
2. After that I check preferences file. It contains 2 keys (KEY_1, KEY_2), like above.
3. Then at 9:00 receiver is executed and getStoredSelectedDays("KEY_1") returns correct set. File contains the same data
4. At 9:10 receiver executes one more time but getStoredSelectedDays("KEY_2") returns empty set. File still contains the same data.

OMG. it's impossible

Comment: And.. How does the file look after that?

Comment: is it possible you are overwriting your saved data by calling method with valid id but null data(because you arraylist is null or empty??  e.g. storeSelectedDays(2, null);

Comment: actually the file contains the same data during whole execution. see ---edited--- part of question